# how to build docker image via php system()

Tags: php, shell, docker-build

I am working to build a docker machine via php system method() its goes to 504 page. i have increased `fastcgi_read_timeout` size 300 to 6000 and `max_execution_time` size 300 to 3000. Stil  goes to 504 page.

**my code:**  `mybuild.php`

```
  $docker_pull = system("cd $this->script_path/;sudo docker build -t reports .", $ret);

    if ($docker_pull != null) {

        print "efk Image pulled correctly";

    } else {

        echo "Error! While docker Pull";         
    }
```

This code works via run command line:

```
php mybuild.php $ag1 $ag2
```

but same file I call via php file its not works 
mytest.php:

```
system("/usr/bin/php mybuild.php $arg1 $agrg2")
```

why?

I add `www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/docker`  to /etc/sudoers file.

**note:** docker container creates fine, but docker build only issue.

Suggest me what i miss in this Configuration and suggest me any other way to did this.

Comment: Never add the www-data user to sudo, especially not with NOPASSWD, this is extremely dangerous. Instead add www-data into the docker group.

Comment: @JazzCat yo mean `www-data : /usr/bin/docker`  this one to add sudoers file right? and what about docker build via php system()?

Comment: Missed /usr/bin/docker as argument, it's a bit safer but still a bad practice. Try absolute searchpath for docker in your system() command /usr/bin/docker build -t reports ...

Comment: Be aware that having access to the docker API or docker CLI equals `root` access to the machine that the docker daemon runs on (e.g. `docker run -v /:/hostroot .....` gives full access to the filesystem (as `root`). This may be fine for an internal system, but be really careful if this machine is accessible over the internet.